# Export WebMap using PrintTask Failing Silverlight API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-silverlight-api, pdf, silverlight

I am using a custom tool to export a webmap to PDF. The tool works successfully through ArcGIS 10.1. The problem crops up when consuming the tool through my Silverlight application using PrintTask. The tool works in an intermittent fashion i.e. sometimes it works, and sometimes it gives an error.

I turned to ArcGIS Manager log and extracted the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File     "C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\Toolbox\ExportPDSitePlanPart.GPServer\extracted\v101\printingtoolbox\ExportPDSitePlan.py", line 48, in result = arcpy.mapping.ConvertWebMapToMapDocument(Web_Map_as_JSON, templateMxd) File "c:\program files\arcgis\server\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 234, in ConvertWebMapToMapDocument return webmap_tuple(*convertArcObjectToPythonObject(arcgisscripting._convertWebMapToMapDocument(webmap_json, template_mxd, notes_gdb, extra_conversion_options))) RuntimeError: Layer "PD Working Layer": Failed to create layer from service at http://10.58.161.70/arcgis/rest/serv...eatureServer/0. Layer "PD Working Layer": Failed to create layer from service at http://10.58.161.70/arcgis/rest/serv...eatureServer/0. Failed to execute (ExportSP). Failed to execute (ExportSP).
```

I can confirm that I can access the service from the same server where the tool is running. (i.e. 10.58.161.70).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the Print Service synchronous? If so try making it an async service under ArcGIS Server as it may be timing out. You can change the sync / async settings by accessing the service under the REST admin services directory.

If it is already asynchronous can you post the error that is returned in the completed event handler and also the trace from the StatusUpdate event.